# WooCommerce address_2 field option value is hidden

Tags: woocommerce

I cannot see billing and shipping address field 2 (`billing_address_field_2` and `shipping_address_field_2`) in checkout page. On debugging further, i found that the option `woocommerce_checkout_address_2_field` is set to hidden in option table.

On searching further i couldn't find any position in WooCommerce where the option `woocommerce_checkout_address_2_field` is added or updated.
Hence i assume the option is reset by some other plugin during its lifetime while the option was not reset to its original option value.

Are there any other instances ? Or is my assumption wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing more about your setup, my advice is quite generic:

Via my themes customise section (Wordpress > Customise > WooCommerce > Checkout) I have an option to enable/disable address 2.

Could you perhaps have a look in that area for something similar. Let me know if this has helped.

[image]

Comment: Exactly. I have seen an option like this but haven't thought about it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks a million! It drove me crazy to figure out why the address_2 was removed.